# In Java, what's the best way to keep top 100 items in a multi-threaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting

I'm running Java 8, my application is a multithreaded search program. It has hundreds of threads; each does some calculation and gets a result with a score, and all the threads put their results into a vector. But I don't want to save all the results, because there are millions of them, too many, and I'm only interested in the results with a score [0 - 100] of 80 or more, and I only want to collect the top 100 of the results, so now in my app I have a vector of size 100. If there is less then 100 item in it, just add to it, when there is 100 item to it, do the following :

```
myVector.set(99,result);
Collestions.sort(myVector);
```

So the last item always has the least score and gets replaced if a new item has higher score.
I wonder if this approach is the best, and is it the fastest? Any other better ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way to do this would be to use a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) (making sure it's a `synchronized` version, if it's multithreaded). A heap allows you to add elements in log time, and also to remove the smallest element in log time.

The Java implementation of a heap is a `PriorityQueue`, or, for a synchronized version, a `PriorityBlockingQueue`. In your case, you're going to want a `PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer>`.

The way to work it is to have a method that will take in a possible thing to add to the heap (i.e., something with a score of 80+), and then

1. count how many elements are in the heap, and if it's less than 100, add this element; OTHERWISE:
2. look at the minimum element in the heap (constant-time operation) and compare it with what you are thinking about adding;
3. if this one has a higher score than the current min, then remove the min (log n operation) and then add this new one in (log n operation).

At the end of the process, your heap will contain the 100 top elements, which you can read off from your heap one by one (in order, from smallest to biggest, just by keeping on removing the min).

(By the way, this kind of heap has nothing to do with the other kind of heap, where memory is allocated for new objects. It's a bit unfortunate to have two key concepts in computer science that have the same name.)

Comment: Very nice answer, but since I'm not familiar with PriorityBlockingQueue, it would be excellent if you can show me a few lines of code as to how to make it happen.

Comment: @Frank You could look at [this article](http://www.journaldev.com/1642/java-priority-queue-priorityqueue-example), which has a nice little example. It uses a `PriorityQueue`, but you use a `PriorityBlockingQueue` in exactly the same way.

Comment: @Frank But you should start by reading the Wikipedia page I linked to, on what heaps are.

Comment: How to "look at the minimum element in the heap" ?

Comment: @Frank that's what the `peek()` method does. The `poll()` method removes the minimum element and returns it to you, but `peek()` returns the minimum element without removing it.

Comment: OK, in the Java doc, it says "the head of this queue", I thought it's the largest of the queue, confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Priority queues come immediately to mind.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

The threadsafe version is `PriorityBlockingQueue`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are two shortcomings:

1. Calling Collections.sort after every modification is rather inefficient, as it requires a couple hundred comparisions.
2. Only one thread can interact with a vector at any time. This imposes a limit on the scalability of the system.

Whether these shortcomings actually matter your application is something we can not assess, as you have not given any performance goals.

For the first item, I'd switch to a java.util.PriorityQueue, which supports efficient removal of the lowest element.

For the second problem, I'd give each thread it's own PriorityQueue, and merge the Queues once all results have been collected. This has the advantage that threads are completely independent in the cpu time intensive phase.

Comment: +1 for good idea on how to avoid serialization in cases where that's an issue.

Comment: Hmm, would need some testing to work out whether this is quicker or slower. If the scores are independent events, then you'd expect to get to a point very quickly where it was rare to find one coming in that would replace what's already stored; and that means most of the results can be thrown away very quickly, because it's a constant-time operation to compare the new one with the min. If you have lots of replacements to make, then it might be an issue.